# Real analysis - proving inequality without using Jensen's inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I wonder how to prove rigorously the following conjecture without the use of Jensen's inequality:

*By the use of the convexity/concavity of appropriate functions of 1 real variable, prove that:*

- $\forall x,y,z\in[0,\pi], \frac{sin(x)+\sin(y)+\sin(z)}{3} \le \sin(\frac{x+y +z}{3})$ (*)

*While inequality in* (*) *becomes an inequality if and only if x=y=z.*

I know that proof of this conjecture is straightforward if one uses Jensen's inequality for the function $f(x):=\sin(x)$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$ and knowing that function f(x) is at that interval concave.

Any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $(x+y+z)/3$ as ${1\over 3}x+{2\over 3}{y+z\over 2}$, and then apply the definition of concavity satisfied by the sine function on $[0,\pi]$ (namely $\sin(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)\ge\lambda\sin(u)+(1-\lambda)\sin(u)$ for $0<\lambda<1$ and $u,v\in[0,\pi]$) twice.